# Transpose of a vector without builtin MATLAB command

Tags: matlab, vector, transpose

Does any one know how I can convert a row vector `[6 8 2]` into a column vector without using a builtin command. I would like to do it without for loop.A ny idea please. Some one asked me is it a home work I say no, it's part of my work. I am trying to convert MATLAB code to vhdl using hdl coder but hdl coder seems not supporting transpose function.

Comment: Can you say why you cannot use the builtin function? Can you only not use `transpose`, or are there other functions you cannot use?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: actually I m trying to convert the code to VHDL in HDL coder.HDL coder does not seem to support transpose function .So if u know any other way please share.Thanks

Comment: @excaza its not some thing like home work stuff. I am a researcher and stuck with this small thing.

Comment: please add this info to your question to make it more complete and so that it does not look like homework. thanks!

Comment: You can increase the chance for getting help by [edit]ing your question and adding those relevant details

Comment: Why can't you use a loop? With pre-allocation this should be very fast.

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to **transpose** or do you want to **convert to a column vector** ?

Comment: I got the solution guys thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `(:)` *trick*

```
t = [1 2 3];
t(:)
ans =

 1
 2
 3
```

**UPDATE**: you should use this method only in the following case: you have a vector (not matrix) and want to make sure it is a column-vector. This method is useful, when you don't know what type (column, row) of vector a variable has.

Check this out

```
t = [1 2 3]'; %// column vector
t(:)
ans =

 1
 2
 3
```

However

```
A=magic(3); 
A(:)
ans =
 8
 3
 4
 1
 5
 9
 6
 7
 2
```

Comment: @Adriaan in the context of the question, which specifies converting a row vector to a column vector, the distinction is meaningless. The transpose of a row vector is a column vector.

Comment: @Adriaan I think this answers the question and is in fact the best choice method. The problem is to get a column vector from a row vector, it really doesn't matter if the solution is conceptually a generic transpose or not. This method works.

Comment: @excaza true, but it nevertheless propagates a bad practise, because if the OP wants to transpose a matrix at some point in his code and thinks the colon operator does just that, he's messing up his code. Therefore whilst it does answer the question, there should be a bit more information about the colon operator and that it *is not a transpose operator* added to the answer in my opinion

Comment: @Adriaan yes, and that was the question, wasn't it? I added your concerns to the answer.

Comment: I think this is fine practice. You can also regard `x = x(:)` as "convert x to a column vector, regardless of whether it was originally a row or column vector". Shows up in my work fairly often.

Answer (score 11):

Some options:

```
R = 1:10; %// A row vector

%// using built-in transpose
C = R';   %'// be warned this finds the complex conjugate
C = R.';  %'// Just swaps the rows and columns
C = transpose(R);    

%// Flattening with the colon operator
C = R(:); %// usually the best option as it also convert columns to columns...

%// Using reshape
C = reshape(R,[],1);

%// Using permute
C = permute(R, [2,1]);

%// Via pre-allocation
C = zeros(numel(R),1);
C(1:end) = R(1:end);

%// Or explicitly using a for loop (note that you really should pre-allocate using zeros for this method as well
C = zeros(numel(R),1); %// technically optional but has a major performance impact
for k = 1:numel(R)
    C(k,1) = R(k);  %// If you preallocated then C(k)=R(k) will work too
end

%// A silly matrix multiplication method
C = diag(ones(numel(R),1)*R)
```

Comment: I'd expect most of these to work. Per [the HDL Coder documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/hdlcoder/ug/functions-supported-for-hdl-code-generation-alphabetical-list.html), `reshape` and `permute` _are_ supported, even though they're built-ins.